# Splitting ItemChildCount

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-query-web-part

Does anyone know how to just return the # of replies value from the built in SP field ItemChildCount? It seems to store the values as a delimited string with the ID of the item associated as a reply and the # of replies. I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in a CQWP, I'm assuming you need to do this in XSLT. There are 2 functions, substring-before and substring-after that you can use. Depending on which part of the string use the appropriate one.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@YourField, 'theDelimiter')" />
```

In your code, when you do the xsl:for-each, you'd add directly below that line an

```
<xsl:sort select="substring-after(@YourField, 'theDelimiter')" order="descending"/>
```

Comment: I can do this in a CQWP but once I have the # im not sure how i would order the items returned by that number. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Updated answer with additional info

Comment: im going to try and hook this up. thank you for the help.

Comment: So i've tried but no no avail. When I order by substringed Itemchildcount w/ xsl:sort it doesn't re-order the results.

Comment: Its like theres something wrong with the ItemChildCount built in field. No matter whay i try to do, it would appear you can't order items by "Replies" or "ItemChildCount"